# How do you connect Django to an existing Microsoft SQL Server DB stored on Azure?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure

I have setup a Django API connected to a React frontend. I'm attempting to connect the Django API to an already existing mssql database on Azure. It's my understanding I need to implement all the existing tables from the database into a models.py file. If that isn't the case and I can access selected tables please let me know.

I've installed pyodbc, djagno-pyodbc-azure, and mssql-django.

In my settings.py I have the data:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',
        'USER': 'USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'PW',
        'HOST' : 'tcp:dbname.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '1442',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            }
    },
}
```

I've tried removing "tcp:" from host, I've tried "sql_server.pyodbc" as the ENGINE. I installed a few different other packages.

Whenever I run "python manage.py inspectdb > models.py" to import the models of the existing database I either get an empty models.py file or an error "django.db.utils.Error: ('01000'...". Feel a bit stuck and was wondering if anyone had some guidance.

Comment: post the full command and full error.

Comment: You probably need to upgrade from `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` ... [it only supports up to SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility).

Comment: Take a look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/mssql-django-samples/mssql-django-samples/ and  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6693/python-django-tutorial-website-sql-server-database/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your configuration. The `USER` should be in `<user>@<servername>` format. And you can keep the `PORT` blank.

The most useful and recommended way to connect the Django App with Azure SQL Database is by following the [django-puodbc-azure](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) README to install python packages `pyodbc` & `django-pyodbc-azure` and configure the `settings.py` file of Django as shown below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

Also, download the correct ODBC driver which is compatible to connect with Azure SQL Database.

Download from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)